# How to redirect traffic to http

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, https

I have an apache server under a proxy that can run HTTPS. Instead of sending the HTTPS=on header, it sends HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO=https.

I want to write an .htaccess rule that redirects all requests from https to http unless the URL is /user/login.

What I've come up with is around these lines (which does an infinite loop):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:http_x_forwarded_proto} !http
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your redirect rule is probably that you're duplicating the "http_" prefix. This shouldn't be necessary. If you have a reverse proxy infront of your server (such as an F5 or nginx), the header will be "X-Forwarded-Proto", or some times "X-Forwarded_Proto". To reference these in a rewrite rule, use %{HTTP:Name-Of-Header} (case is not sensitive).

For the most robust rewrite that works in all situations, use something like this:

```
# Make sure all SSL pages for dot-com are redirected to HTTP.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded_Proto} https
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Some more detail about using headers in RewriteCond is given in the [Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your initial condition is that you have !http instead of !=http. That may fix the infinite loop.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:http_x_forwarded_proto} !=http
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/login.*
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This should take any https request that is not /user/login and rewrite it to http. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, though. You could get rid of RewriteCond %{HTTP:http_x_forwarded_proto} !=http and it would probably work just as well, for example, since it should take any request handed to it that does not include /user/login and redirect it to http.

Comment: Doesn't work either. I've opted for a redirect from my application for now, because I needed something fast, but I'd still be open for a htaccess redirect if it's possible.